# finding core dump of program that ran with qemu-arm-static

Tags: gdb, qemu, coredump

I ran a program with `qemu-arm-static`

the program crashed with the following error:

```
qemu: uncaught target signal 6 (Aborted) - core dumped
Aborted (core dumped)
```

how can i get the core dump?

Thanks.